# Is this possible? Iterating @keyframes with CSS (Stylus)

Tags: css, node.js, iteration, stylus, css-animations

I have this code in Stylus:

```
for i in (1..3)
  .l:nth-child({i})
     opacity (i / 5)
```

Which outputs:

```
.l:nth-child(1) {
opacity: 0.2;
}
.l:nth-child(2) {
opacity: 0.4;
 }
.l:nth-child(3) {
 opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Which is great, but I want to change this so that the opacity is 0 at the start and to be set after using @keyframes dynamically;

```
@keyframes o 
0%
 opacity 0 
100%  
  for i in (1..3)
  opacity (i / 5)
```

Returns, the obviously incorrect:

```
100% {
opacity: 0.2;
opacity: 0.4;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Not sure how to do this, do I need to use a function? Thanks for your time! The result I want should look like this:

```
100% {
.l:nth-child(1) {
opacity: 0.2;
}
.l:nth-child(2) {
opacity: 0.4;
 }
.l:nth-child(3) {
 opacity: 0.6;
}
}
```

Comment: You will need a different set of keyframes for all elements, you can't put selectors inside a keyframe's step definition, only `property: value;` pairs.

Comment: Ahhhh thought so, thanks man! So you mean I will end up having: keyframes o1, keyframes o2, keyframes o3... etc. And each opacity in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by creating a keyframe for each iteration:

```
for i in (1..3)
 $keyframe-name = (o- + i)
 @keyframes {$keyframe-name} 
   0% 
   100%
    opacity (i/5)
```

And then animating:

```
for i in (1..3)
 .l:nth-child({i})
   opacity 0
   animation (o- + i) 0.25s (i/5)s linear forwards
```

Thanks @DJDavid98 for your comment.